# Inertia groups generating Galois groups 

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

It is known that if K is a ﬁnite Galois extension of Q with Galois group G, then G is generated by the inertia groups of ramiﬁed primes in the extension.

Does the statement hold for infinite Galois extensions?

Comment: Doesn't it have to do with the fact that $\mathbf{Q}$
has no unramified extension of degree $>1$ ?

Comment: Please don't post at two places simultaneously. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21829/inertia-groups-generating-galois-groups

Comment: If you want this question to be reopened, please delete the cross-posted question and flag for moderator attention.

Answer (score 9):

Writing an infinite Galois group as the projective limit of finite Galois groups, one sees that the inertia groups in the infinite extension topologically generate the infinite Galois group.